# Floating tree panel's blur listener not called

Tags: layout, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, treepanel

I have a floating tree panel that shows (showBy) up below a combo box when I click on it. I would like a click outside the tree panel to hide it so I am trying a blur listener that is pasted below. But the blur listener is not called on click outside of the panel.

```
                    blur: function(tree, event, opts) {
                        treePanel.setVisible(false);
                    }
```

I also tried setting blur listener on tree panel's "el" but then on click of a tree node itself fires this listener. I don't completely understand why this happens.

```
                    el: {
                        blur: function() {
                            treePanel.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    }
```

Can someone suggest how I should approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you get the focus event to fire? Perhaps it is never really in focus, so it can never lose focus. Also, if you post more of your code, perhaps in a working jsfiddle, it'll be easier to debug.

Comment: The focus event does not fire too. I check document.activeElement and that shows the tree view div.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the focus on your floating grid. `blur` will only work if the component looses focus. In order to loose the focus, it must first get the focus.

In your code replace `treePanel.setVisible(true);` with

```
treePanel.setVisible(true)
treePanel.focus()
```